# How to do an atomic "get & Clear" on a ConcurrentHashMap in Java?

Tags: java, collections, concurrenthashmap

I'd like to do an Atomic `getAndClear()` on a ConcurrentHashMap.

I'd like to **periodically** handle all elements in the map, clearing the map afterwards. Once in a while, data is inserted again and after a period of time, I'm doing the same handling again.

The data structure is a `map` in order to prevent duplicates. It's also a `ConcurrentHashMap` in order to to support putting data from several threads.

Option 1: I can handle each element and removing it after it's handled. The problem is that new elements with the same key might be inserted, which will be handled again at the same time and not periodically.

Option 2: Synchronize and block insertion while I drain the map. Don't want to do that.

Option 3: The best I came up with: Using `AtomicReference.getAndSet()`. Should work but make the usage a bit cumbersome.

Any idea if there's an API, wrapper or some other way to achieve this goal? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to remove all elements anyways you could try to atomically replace the map itself :)

Comment: I'm with @Thomas - if you have access to the variable that store the writer's reference to the map, replace it.

If you don't, you can instead only block insertion while you COPY & CLEAR the map (shoudl be qucik enough) and process the copy while the writer can fill the original map again.

Comment: wondering what the use case for this is... and what do you lose, if you don't do it atomically (i.e. retrieve and afterwards clearing it)? If I understand it correctly there might be a chance that other threads put in data that gets cleared too early... but why is there even sense in clearing the map if just one specific item is found?

Comment: @Roland the way I understood it, one or multiple writers put data into the map, and may override a specific key at any time. however, every key should only be processed with ONE value at each processing cycle. Now without synchronization, one key could be processed (and cleared to not process it again) but re-added by another thread before the processing cycle is done, and will get processed a second time.

Comment: What I would do is extend ConcurrentHashMap and add a `synchronized` "getAndClear" method that allows a map to return a (deep, if necessary) copy ofitself and then clear itself.

Comment: @JohannesH. Isn't that just a different implementation of option 2, which he's already rejected?

Comment: @Michael it is not. Blocking the Map while "draining" it (aka removing one element after another whiel processing them) results in a way longer block for the writer thread than copying it (at least if we assume that the native java collections implement clones by copying the underlying structures completely and not iterating voer them)

Comment: Replacing the map itself does the job. No need for the AtomicReference. Why didn't I think of this myself? Thanks @Thomas

Comment: @Michael there is also no way around this, as copying and clearing are always two seperate actions that are called after another. therefore, if we do not block othre threads from doing anything inbetween those actions, data could be inserted after the copy and before the clear and would be lost. Well, besides chaing the entire map and writing into a new one.

Comment: So now the questions changes to how to replace the ConcurrentHashMap Atomically - Another thread might be using the instance. I can create a ReadWriteLock, adding to the map when in read lock and replacing the map when in write lock, but this seems quite cumbersome.